# I'm confused as to how to write code for a change refunding machine with various loops

Tags: java

I wanted to write some code that takes a customer's payment for an item with a predetermined purchase price. I wanted to make it so that if the customer enters an amount lower than the purchase price, they are prompted to enter another dollar amount until their payment finally covers the cost. If they give the exact amount then no change is given, but if they don't give the exact amount a message similar to this would appear:

$20.00 remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: $10.00

$10.00 remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: $15.00

You gave $25.00, your change is: 1 x $5.00

This is the code i have so far:

```
String customerPayment;
  System.out.print("\n" + defaultFormat.format(purchasePrice) + " remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ");
  customerPayment = keyboard.next();
  while (!customerPayment.startsWith("$")) {
    System.out.println("\nInvalid coin or note. Try again.");
    System.out.print("\n" + defaultFormat.format(purchasePrice) + " remains to be paid. Enter coin or note in the form '$##.##': ");
    customerPayment = keyboard.next();
  } 
  while (customerPayment < purchasePrice) {
    System.out.print((purchasePrice - customerPayment) + " left to be paid. Enter note or coin: ");
    customerPayment = keyboard.next();
```

I have used a String value for customerPayment so that i can test for the '$', but whenever i parseDouble the String i receive a compiler error. How would i go about coding this customer payment problem in the simplest possible way?

Comment: what does the compiler error say?

Comment: anyway, this: customerPayment < purchasePrice makes no sense. I don't know what purchasePrice is, but customerPayment is a String, not a numerical value.

Comment: to get double value from string like `"$10.00"`, use `double d = Double.parseDouble(s.replace("$", ""))`

Comment: Why do you include the "$" character? Is it really necessary? It would only be used to display the result. Thing would get a lot easier if you only used `double` variables.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the user for a numerical value and expect it to be dollars?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\$(?!0[^.])(\\d+(?:\\.\\d{2})?)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the NumberFormat currency:

```
public static void main(String... a){
    if(a.length<1){
        System.err.println("The first argument is the price of the item.");
        return;
    }
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    final double PRICE=Double.parseDouble(a[0]);
    double remaining=PRICE;
    while(remaining>0){         
        String input = System.console().readLine(currency.format(remaining) + " remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ");
        Double x=null;
        try {
            x = currency.parse(input).doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid coin or note. Try again.");
        }
        if(x!=null) remaining-=x;
    }
    if(remaining!=0)
        System.out.println("You gave " + currency.format(PRICE - remaining) + ", your change is " + currency.format(-remaining));
}
```